# UML state chart - is it legal to exit a composite state from a meta state

Tags: uml, state, meta

Is it "legal" to for the only transition out of a composite state to originate from a decision node as shown in the picture?

http://pokit.org/get/?7358c1cf25ccd026b9ebe528768b0eb5.jpg

Yeah, I know the writing seems like I'm speaking in tongues. :) Apart from that, does the diagram make sense like this and is it valid according to UML rules?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: i looks all right to me. Generally u shouldn't include a decision node in a state diagram. Just have two seperate lines going out of the square. Just my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Just to clarify, when you say I shouldn't do it, do you mean it's wrong this way or it's just not the way it's usually done?

Comment: The rules in UML are not as hard as you think. The aim of a programming language is to make something work, UMLs aim is to communicate something. As long as the diagram communicates an idea then it should be fine. If you dig deep enough in the UML specs you might find if its allowed or not. But generally UML allows much more than you think.

Comment: Using a decision note in a state diagram is absolutely permitted. They are typically used if there is a computation needed before a choice is made or when a guard's evaluation on multiple transitions with the same trigger have to be done in a specific order. In some cases, they also make the state machine easier to read. For cases where the guards are simple (e.g., true/false) they may not be required. It also depends on your organisation's standards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For full UML (2.5) compliance, you would need entryPoint and exitPoint pseudostates when you enter or exit a state. However, these are often not shown when there is no transition to/from a substate or when hierarchical state history is not tracked.

So you would need an entryPoint pseudostate on the Zapoceta state that would act as the "bridge" between the initial point and the Nepotpuna states.

Similarly, you would also need an exitPoint pseudostate in the Zapoceta state that would act as the "bridge" between the choice pseudostate and the Potpuna state.

Also, you would not need an "or" constraint on the transitions between the Obracunata and Placena states. What you would have are different triggers for each transition. Having multiple transitions out of a state machine implies that the transitions' triggers are mutually exclusive.